# C program not writing correctly into a variable

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, heap

I am making a program which calculates the minimum spanning tree of each vertex in a graph. And in this piece of code (analysis.c), this is the part of the program that gets buggy:

```
    int _i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int max=0;

    // Initialize min heap with all vertices. weight value of all vertices  
    for (_i = 0; _i < graph_dim; _i++){
        weight[_i].type = NO_ROUTE;          //Default queremos que seja o "pior" weight
        weight[_i].dist = 0;
        if(graph[_i] != NULL){               //Se for um elemento que pertence ao grafo
            heap->table[j]->vertex = _i; 
            heap->pos[_i] = j;
            j++;
        }

        if(_i == 8){
            for (int crl = 0; crl < vertex_num; crl++){
                printf("heap->table[crl]->vertex=%d\n", heap->table[crl]->vertex);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
106             if(graph[_i] != NULL){               //Se for um elemento que pertence ao grafo
(gdb) print _i
$51 = 5
(gdb) print j
$52 = 4
(gdb) print heap->table[0]->vertex
$53 = 1
(gdb) s
107                 heap->table[j]->vertex = _i; 
(gdb) print _i
$54 = 5
(gdb) print j
$55 = 4
(gdb) print heap->table[0]->vertex
$56 = 1
(gdb) s
108                 heap->pos[_i] = j;
(gdb) print _i
$57 = 5
(gdb) print j
$58 = 4
(gdb) print heap->table[0]->vertex
$59 = 5
(gdb) print heap->table[j]->vertex
$60 = 5
```

As you can see, when j = 4 and _i = 5, before making this instruction:

```
heap->table[j]->vertex = _i;
```

heap->table[0]->vertex is 1
and after making that instruction, the program instead of writing in table[4], it writes in table[0]...
You can clearly see it on gdb.

This is the main function:

```
int main(){
    /*
    char option,option3;
    char option2;
    int dest=0;*/
    long int statResult[3];
    statResult[0]=0;
    statResult[1]=0;
    statResult[2]=0;

    int i;

    createGraph();
    initDijkstra(graph_dim);


    for(i = 1; i < graph_dim; i++){
        if(graph[i] != NULL){
            dijkstra(i,0,&statResult[0],&statResult[1],&statResult[2]);
            /*printf("source = %d\n", i);
            printWeight();
            printf("\n");*/
        }
    }
```

The bugs only start after the first djikstra has been done so, it made me believe that there was some cleaning left to do between djikstras...

So a little context:

graph_dim is a global variable which the value stays the same the entire program: graph_dim = 9;

this is the allocation made for heap: (heap->table is a vector of pointers)

```
    heap = (Min_Heap*) malloc(sizeof(Min_Heap));
    if(heap == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    heap->pos = (int*)malloc(graph_dim*sizeof(int));
    if(heap->pos == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    heap->table = (Min_Heap_Node**)malloc(7*sizeof(Min_Heap_Node*));
    if(heap->pos == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        heap->table[i] = (Min_Heap_Node*)malloc(sizeof(Min_Heap_Node));
        if(heap->table[i] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

This is like the craziest bug that ever happenned to me, I'm starting to believe dark magic.

Does someone have a clue?

Here's all the code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "graph.h"
#include "heap.h"
#include "analysis.h"

int graph_dim = 0;
int vertex_num = 0;
Node_List_Adj** graph = NULL;
Weight* weight = NULL;        // weight values used to pick minimum weight edge in cut 
Min_Heap* heap = NULL;

void printWeight(void){
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < graph_dim; i++){
        if(graph[i] == NULL){
            printf("Not part of graph\n");
        }else{
            printf("Dest=%d | type=%d | dist = %d\n", i, (int)weight[i].type, weight[i].dist);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    /*
    char option,option3;
    char option2;
    int dest=0;*/
    long int statResult[3];
    statResult[0]=0;
    statResult[1]=0;
    statResult[2]=0;

    int i;

    createGraph();
    initDijkstra(graph_dim);


    for(i = 1; i < graph_dim; i++){
        if(graph[i] != NULL){
            dijkstra(i,0,&statResult[0],&statResult[1],&statResult[2]);
            /*printf("source = %d\n", i);
            printWeight();
            printf("\n");*/
        }
    }
}
```

analysis.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "analysis.h"
#include "graph.h"

//extern int export_route[3][3];
extern int graph_dim;
extern int vertex_num;
extern Node_List_Adj** graph;
extern Weight* weight;
extern Min_Heap* heap;

int cmpTypes(int smallest, int other){
    static const int cmp_types[4][4] = {
                    //CUSTOMER     PEER      PROVIDER     NO_ROUTE
    /*CUSTOMER*/    { IS_EQUAL,     1      ,    1       ,     1     } ,      //CUSTOMER é melhor que PEER e PROVIDER
    /*PEER    */    {    0    ,  IS_EQUAL  ,    1       ,     1     } ,      //PEER é pior que COSTUMER e melhor que PEER
    /*PROVIDER*/    {    0    ,     0      , IS_EQUAL   ,     1     } ,      //PROVIDER é pior que COSTUMER e pior que PEER
    /*NO_ROUTE*/    {    0    ,     0      ,    0       ,  IS_EQUAL }
    };

    return cmp_types[smallest][other];
}

int exportRoute(int relation_last_node, int connection_type){
    //                            (relation_2_last_node, connection_type)
    static const int export_route[        3           ][       3       ] = {
    //connection_type CUSTOMER     PEER      PROVIDER
    //relation_last_node
    /*CUSTOMER*/    {    1    ,     0      ,    0    } ,     //O customer só quer exportar os seus customers
    /*PEER    */    {    1    ,     0      ,    0    } ,     //O peer só quer exportar os seus customers
    /*PROVIDER*/    {    1    ,     1      ,    1    }       //O provider que exportar todas as suas ligações
    };
    return export_route[relation_last_node][connection_type];
}


//Compara o weight do smallest com o weight do other: retorna 1 se o smallest 
//tem o smallest weight e 0 se o contrario acontecer
char hasSmallestWeight(Weight smallest, Weight other){

    char res = cmpTypes(smallest.type-1, other.type-1);
    if(res == IS_EQUAL){
        if(smallest.dist < other.dist){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

// A utility function to alloc necessary data structures do perform dijkstra()
void initDijkstra(int capacity){ 
    weight = (Weight*)malloc(graph_dim*sizeof(Weight));
    if(weight == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    heap = (Min_Heap*) malloc(sizeof(Min_Heap));
    if(heap == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    heap->pos = (int*)malloc(graph_dim*sizeof(int));
    if(heap->pos == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    heap->table = (Min_Heap_Node**)malloc(7*sizeof(Min_Heap_Node*));
    if(heap->pos == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        heap->table[i] = (Min_Heap_Node*)malloc(sizeof(Min_Heap_Node));
        if(heap->table[i] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Erro alocar memoria");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
} 

// The main function that calulates distances of shortest paths from src to all 
// vertices. It is a O(ELogV) function 
void dijkstra(int src, int stat, long int* c, long int*r, long int*p){
    Min_Heap_Node* actual_heap_node;
    Node_List_Adj* actual_adj;
    Weight candidate_weight;
    int q = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int max=0;

    // Initialize min heap with all vertices. weight value of all vertices  
    for (q = 0; q < graph_dim; q++){
        weight[q].type = NO_ROUTE;          //Default queremos que seja o "pior" weight
        weight[q].dist = 0;
        if(graph[q] != NULL){               //Se for um elemento que pertence ao grafo
            heap->table[j]->vertex = q; 
            heap->pos[q] = j;
            j++;
        }

        if(q == 8){
            for (int crl = 0; crl < vertex_num; crl++){
                printf("heap->table[crl]->vertex=%d\n", heap->table[crl]->vertex);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    //Initially size of min heap is equal to vertex_num
    heap->size = vertex_num; 

    //Update heap and weight
    candidate_weight.dist = 0;
    candidate_weight.type = (char)CUSTOMER;

    updateHeapWeight(src, (char)PROVIDER, candidate_weight); //relation_2_last_node como PROVIDER para a source anunciar todas as suas routes


    //printf("pos[4]=%d dps\n", heap->pos[4]);
    // Extract the src 

    actual_heap_node = extractMin(heap); 

    candidate_weight.dist = 1;
    //Correr por todos os adjacentes do src (são todos reachable)
    for(actual_adj = graph[actual_heap_node->vertex]; actual_adj != NULL; actual_adj = actual_adj->next){
        candidate_weight.type = actual_adj->edge_type;
        updateHeapWeight(actual_adj->dest, actual_adj->edge_type, candidate_weight);
        if(src == 8){
           // printMinHeap(0, 1);
            //printf("weight[4].type=%d\n", weight[4].type);
        }

    }

    // In the followin loop, min heap contains all nodes except src
    // whose shortest weight is not yet finalized. 
    while (!isEmpty(heap)){
        // Extract the vertex with minimum weight value 
        actual_heap_node = extractMin(heap);

        if(weight[actual_heap_node->vertex].type == NO_ROUTE){
            break;
        }

        //Correr por todos os adjacentes do actual_adj
        for(actual_adj = graph[actual_heap_node->vertex]; actual_adj != NULL; actual_adj = actual_adj->next){

            //Se não for uma ligação anunciável -> continue
            if(!exportRoute(actual_heap_node->relation_2_last_node-1, actual_adj->edge_type-1)){
                continue;
            }

            //Se o weight do dest já estiver finalizado e posto no weight[] (já n tá na heap) -> continue
            if(!IS_IN_HEAP(actual_adj->dest)){
                continue;
            }

            candidate_weight.type = weight[actual_heap_node->vertex].type;
            candidate_weight.dist = weight[actual_heap_node->vertex].dist +1;

            if(!hasSmallestWeight(weight[actual_adj->dest], candidate_weight)){
                // update weight value in min heap also 
                updateHeapWeight(actual_adj->dest, actual_adj->edge_type, candidate_weight);
            }
        }

        if (weight[actual_heap_node->vertex].dist > max)
        {
            max=weight[actual_heap_node->vertex].dist;
        }

    }



     if (stat==1)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < graph_dim; a++)
        {


            switch(weight[a].type){

          case CUSTOMER:

              *c += 1;
              break;
            case PEER:
              *r += 1;
              break;
            case PROVIDER:
              *p += 1;
              break;

            }

        }

    }else if(stat==0){

        for (int a = 0; a < graph_dim; a++)
        {
              switch(weight[a].type){

          case CUSTOMER:
              //printf("De %d para %d :(c,%d)\n",a,src,weight[a].dist);
              break;
            case PEER:
              //printf("De %d para %d :(r,%d)\n",a,src,weight[a].dist);
              break;
            case PROVIDER:
              //printf("De %d para %d :(p,%d)\n",a,src,weight[a].dist);
              break;

           }
        }

        }else if (stat==2){


            //double c_cdf[max];
            //printf("%d\n",max );

              for (int a = 0; a <= max; a++)
        {

            //c_cdf[a]=cumulativeNormal((double)a,(double)max);
            //printf("leght: %d -> prob: %lf\n",a,c_cdf[a] );

        }

    }
}

double cumulativeNormal(double x, double max) {
  // return  1-(0.5 * erfc(((max/1 -  x)) * sqrt(0.5)));
}
```

analysis.h:

```
#ifndef _ANALYSIS_H
#define _ANALYSIS_H

#include "heap.h"

#define CUSTOMER 1      //No ficheiro vem em 3
#define PEER 2
#define PROVIDER 3      //No ficheiro vem em 1
#define NO_ROUTE 4
#define IS_EQUAL 2

int cmpTypes(int smallest, int other);
int exportRoute(int relation_last_node, int connection_type);
void initDijkstra(int capacity);
char hasSmallestWeight(Weight smallest, Weight other);
void dijkstra(int src,int stat, long int* c, long int*r, long int*p);
double cumulativeNormal(double x,double max );

#endif
```

heap.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "graph.h"
#include "heap.h"
#include "analysis.h"

extern int graph_dim;
extern Weight* weight;
extern Min_Heap* heap;


// A utility function to check if a given vertex 
// 'vertex' is in min heap or not 
#define IS_IN_HEAP(_vertex) ((heap->pos[(_vertex)] < heap->size) ? 1 : 0)

// A utility function to swap two nodes of min heap. Needed for min heapify 
void swapMinHeapNode(Min_Heap_Node** a, Min_Heap_Node** b){ 
    Min_Heap_Node* t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
}

// A standard function to heapify at given idx 
// This function also updates position of nodes when they are swapped. 
// Position is needed for updateHeapWeight() 
void minHeapify(int index){
    int smallest, left, right; 
    Min_Heap_Node* index_node;
    Min_Heap_Node* smallest_node;

    smallest = index; 
    left = 2 * index + 1; 
    right = 2 * index + 2; 

    if (left < heap->size && !hasSmallestWeight(weight[heap->table[smallest]->vertex], weight[heap->table[left]->vertex])){
        smallest = left; 
    }

    if (right < heap->size && !hasSmallestWeight(weight[heap->table[smallest]->vertex], weight[heap->table[right]->vertex])){
        smallest = right; 
    }

    if (smallest != index){ 
        // The nodes to be swapped in min heap 
        smallest_node = heap->table[smallest]; 
        index_node = heap->table[index]; 

        // Swap positions 
        heap->pos[smallest_node->vertex] = index; 
        heap->pos[index_node->vertex] = smallest; 

        // Swap nodes 
        swapMinHeapNode(&heap->table[smallest], &heap->table[index]); 

        minHeapify(smallest); 
    } 
} 

// A utility function to check if the given heap is empty or not 
char isEmpty(){ 
    return !(heap->size); 
} 

// Standard function to extract minimum node from heap 
Min_Heap_Node* extractMin(){
    Min_Heap_Node* lastNode;
    Min_Heap_Node* root;

    if (isEmpty(heap)){
        return NULL;
    }

    // Store the root node 
    root = heap->table[0]; 

    // Replace root node with last node 
    lastNode = heap->table[heap->size-1]; 
    heap->table[0] = lastNode; 

    // Update position of last node 
    heap->pos[root->vertex] = heap->size-1; 
    heap->pos[lastNode->vertex] = 0; 

    // Reduce heap size and heapify root 
    (heap->size)--; 
    minHeapify(0); 

    return root; 
}

// Function to decreasy weight value of a given vertex. This function 
// uses pos[] of min heap to get the current index of vertex in min heap 
void updateHeapWeight(int vertex, int relation_2_last_node, Weight _weight){
    // Get the index of vertex in heap array 
    int i = heap->pos[vertex]; 

    if(vertex == 4){
        i = heap->pos[vertex];
    }

    heap->table[i]->relation_2_last_node = relation_2_last_node;
    weight[vertex] = _weight;

    // Travel up while the complete tree is not hepified. 
    // This is a O(Logn) loop 
    //Enquando não chegamos à root ou enquanto o nosso nó 'i' da heap não está bem posicionado
    while (i && !hasSmallestWeight(weight[heap->table[(i-1)/2]->vertex], weight[heap->table[i]->vertex])){
        // Swap this node with its parent 
        heap->pos[heap->table[i]->vertex] = (i-1)/2;
        heap->pos[heap->table[(i-1)/2]->vertex] = i; 
        swapMinHeapNode(&heap->table[i], &heap->table[(i-1)/2]);

        // move to parent index 
        i = (i - 1) / 2; 
    }
}

void printMinHeap(int index, int depth){
    int left, right;

    left = 2 * index + 1; 
    right = 2 * index + 2; 

    /* Make sure item exists */
    if (index >= heap->size) 
        return; 

    for(int i = 0; i < depth; i++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("top=%d\n", heap->table[index]->vertex); 

    printf("left=%d right = %d\n\n", heap->table[left]->vertex, heap->table[right]->vertex);
} 


// A utility function to check if a given vertex 
// 'vertex' is in min heap or not 
/*char isInMinHeap(int vertex){
   if (heap->pos[vertex] < heap->size){
        return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
*/
```

heap.h:

```
#ifndef _HEAP_H
#define _HEAP_H

//THIS IS A MIN HEAP


//Structure to represent a element of the vector containg the weights to each destinantion
typedef struct{
    int type;
    int dist;
}Weight;


// Structure to represent a min heap node 
typedef struct{
    int vertex;
    int relation_2_last_node;
}Min_Heap_Node; 

// Structure to represent a min heap 
typedef struct{ 
    int size;       // Number of heap nodes present currently 
    int capacity;   // Capacity of min heap 
    int *pos;       // Tabela que diz qual é a posição de um vertex na heap
    Min_Heap_Node** table;  //Vetor de ponteiros para nós de heap -> esta tabela vai ter tamanho vertex_num (numero de nos pertencentes ao grafo) <= graph_dim
}Min_Heap; 

#define IS_IN_HEAP(_vertex) ((heap->pos[(_vertex)] < heap->size) ? 1 : 0)

void swapMinHeapNode(Min_Heap_Node** a, Min_Heap_Node** b);
void minHeapify(int index);
char isEmpty();
Min_Heap_Node* extractMin();
void updateHeapWeight(int vertex, int relation_2_last_node, Weight _weight);
void printMinHeap(int index, int depth);
//char isInMinHeap(int vertex);


#endif
```

graph.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "io.h"
#include "graph.h"


extern int graph_dim;
extern int vertex_num;
extern Node_List_Adj** graph;


void createGraph(){
    FILE* file_fd = NULL;
    int src;
    int dest;
    int type;
    int i;

    //Obter o tamanho do vetor de adjacencias vendo qual é o seu maior index necessário
    graph_dim = getASMaxIndex(&file_fd)+1;


    //Abrir o ficheiro
    file_fd = fopen(FILE_LOCATION, "r");
    if(file_fd == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    //Alocar a memória necessária para o grafo, representado por uma lista/vetor de adjacencias
    graph = (Node_List_Adj**)malloc(graph_dim*sizeof(Node_List_Adj*));
    if(graph == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocationg memory\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Inicializar o vetor
    for(i = 0; i < graph_dim; i++){
        graph[i] = NULL;
    }

    while(fscanf(file_fd, "%d %d %d", &src, &dest, &type) == 3){
        addEdge(src, dest, type);
    }

    fclose(file_fd);
}


// Adds an edge to an undirected graph 
void addEdge(int src, int dest, char type){ 
    Node_List_Adj* new_node = NULL;

    // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is added to the adjacency 
    // list of src.  The node is added at the beginning 

    new_node = (Node_List_Adj*)malloc(sizeof(Node_List_Adj));
    if(new_node == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocationg memory\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    new_node->dest = dest;
    new_node->edge_type = type;

    if(graph[src] == NULL){
        vertex_num++;
    }

    new_node->next = graph[src];
    graph[src] = new_node; 
}
```

graph.h:

```
#ifndef _GRAPH_H
#define _GRAPH_H

typedef struct List_Adj_Struct{
    struct List_Adj_Struct* next;
    int dest;
    int edge_type;
}Node_List_Adj;


void createGraph();
void addEdge(int src, int dest, char type);

#endif
```

io.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "io.h"

int getASMaxIndex(){
    int max = 0;
    int num;
    FILE*file_fd = NULL;

    //Abrir o ficheiro
    file_fd = fopen(FILE_LOCATION, "r");
    if(file_fd == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(fscanf(file_fd, "%d ", &num) != EOF){
        if(max < num){
            max = num;
        }

    }
    fclose(file_fd);
    return max;
}
```

io.h:

```
#ifndef _IO_H
#define _IO_H

#define FILE_LOCATION "./table.txt"  //Localização do ficheiro de input da tabela


int getASMaxIndex();

#endif
```

example table.txt with a graph:

```
1 2 1
2 1 3
2 3 1
2 4 2
2 6 3
3 5 3
3 2 3
4 2 2
4 8 1
5 3 1
5 8 3
6 2 1
8 4 3
8 5 1
```

Comment: Did you try running it under an analyzer that checks for memory errors like `valgrind`?

Comment: Do not prefix your variables with an underscore. Those names are reserved for the compiler and standard libraries. It is probably not the bug you are looking for, but when the planets are correctly aligned, it *might*.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
after running valgrind. It only says I have memory leaks, that's normal because I don't do any free()

Comment: @HAL9000 changed "_i" "q". I guess the planets aren't aligned :|

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @EmployedRussian just pasted all the code I'm using.

Comment: @francis2tm it looks not like a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: well but still, how is it possible that gdb output? As far as I know gdb doesn't skip instructions..